# non mandatory Lookup field - prevent delete if children present

Tags: apex

I have a non mandatory lookup field on a custom object C, which is the child of another custom object P. Now I want to prevent an record of P from being deleted if it has child C records. Is there any non programmatic solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the highlighted block for that lookup field in the below image. If you checked then it won't allow to delete the parent object if any child record present under that parent.

[image]

Comment: My bad, I missed that one completely. I though it was only possible if lookup was mandatory.